# Android Studio SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi i'm beginner in Android app. I have a many errors and app is not starting.

`E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.home.lab4/com.example.home.lab4.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not unique (code 19)`

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        User b = new User(1,"London", "123456");
        db.addUser(b);


        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all users...");
        List<User> users = db.getAllUsers();

        for(User us : users ) {
            String log = "Username: " + us.getName() + " ,Password: " + us.getPassword();
            Log.d("Name: ", log);
        }

        db.close();
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText usernametext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
                String username = usernametext.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText passwordtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
                String password = passwordtext.getText().toString();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // DB information
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user";
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if ( cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                user.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
                user.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
                userList.add(user);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return userList;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
public class User {
    int _id;
    String _username;
    String _password;

    public User(){

    }
    public User(int id, String username, String password){
        this._id = id;
        this._username = username;
        this._password = password;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this._username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return this._password;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username){
        this._username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this._password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

Comment: @KaklotarHarin You can call your id column whatever you want.

Comment: id is integer autoincrement

Comment: @FrankN.Stein sometime sqLite error because of this

Comment: @KaklotarHarin NO. You are referring to CursorAdapters which require an `_id` field

Comment: i already executed string but same problem

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes you are right, I am sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein how to fix my error

Comment: There's an answer, in the provided link (duplicate question).